# Function definition(?) without {}

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I was reading [avio.h](http://svn.perian.org/ffmpeg/libavformat/avio.h) (part of ffmpeg) and there is definition(?) like this:

`int avio_printf(AVIOContext *s, const char *fmt, ...) av_printf_format(2, 3);`.

I don't get it. Could someone explain me what this do? Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`av_printf_format` is a macro, which can optionally add a GCC attribute to the function declaration. It's defined [in attributes.h](http://svn.perian.org/ffmpeg/libavutil/attributes.h):

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#    define av_builtin_constant_p __builtin_constant_p
#    define av_printf_format(fmtpos, attrpos) __attribute__((__format__(__printf__, fmtpos, attrpos)))
#else
#    define av_builtin_constant_p(x) 0
#    define av_printf_format(fmtpos, attrpos)
#endif
```

So this is actually a function declaration, which may have a specific attribute if compiled on GCC.

The `format` attribute tells GCC that the function takes its arguments like `printf`, which helps diagnose some errors.